# How can I use settings with reloadOnChange and LoggingLevelSwitch in Serilog

Tags: serilog

Using Serilog and Serilog.Settings.Configuration in .NET Core 2, I'd like to do something like the following. Is it possible?

`appsettings.json`

```
{
  "Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "ControlledBy": {
        "Serilog.Core.LoggingLevelSwitch": "Debug"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

`program.cs`

```
var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder().SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", reloadOnChange: true)
    //...
    .Build();

Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
    //...
    .CreateLogger();
```

My intent is to modify the config file and have the log level change without restarting the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works straight out of the box with the normal `"MinimumLevel": "Debug"` syntax.